# C# Deserialize JSON with Key Name Starting with String

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "fs_Unique_Form_Name": {
        "title": "Title Text",
        "description": "This is the description.",
        "code": "123"
    },
    "stackId": 1,
    "stateId": 1,
    "timeStamp": "2020-11-04:10.30.48"
}
```

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to try and deserialize it to a model object, but am having a hard time with the dynamic keys; I'd like to make that property generic if possible since the inner object is always the same.

Here are the models I am trying to use:

```
public class FormDetail {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class FormResponse {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NEED TO FIGURE THIS OUT")]
    public FormDetail FormDetail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "stackId")]
    public int StackId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "stateId")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timeStamp")]
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get the whole JSON deserialized into the `FormResponse` object, but am having difficulty because the `fs_Unique_Form_Name` key is dynamic after the `fs_` portion, but the keys (title, description, code) in that object are static.

Is there a way for me to do something where I can deserialize it to the `FormDetail` property when the JSON key starts with `fs_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by making a custom `JsonConverter` for your `FormResponse` class.  Below is the code you would need for the converter:

```
public class FormResponseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(FormResponse);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Load the JSON into a JObject so we can inspect it.
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Populate all the known properties on a new instance of FormResponse.
        FormResponse response = new FormResponse();
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), response);

        // Now find the first property in the JObject whose name starts with "fs_".
        // If there is one, use it to populate the FormDetail on the response.
        JProperty prop = obj.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.StartsWith("fs_"));
        response.FormDetail = prop != null ? prop.Value.ToObject<FormDetail>(serializer) : null;

        return response;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your `FormResponse` class as shown below.  You can remove the `[JsonProperty]` attribute from the `FormDetail` property as it is not needed.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FormResponseConverter))]
public class FormResponse
{
    public FormDetail FormDetail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "stackId")]
    public int StackId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "stateId")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timeStamp")]
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize as you normally would:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormResponse>(json);
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jHyRcK

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.

For example, let's create a custom reader.

```
class CustomJsonReader : JsonTextReader
{
    public CustomJsonReader(TextReader reader) : base(reader) { }

    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName &&
                base.Value.ToString().StartsWith("fs_"))
                return "FormDetail";

            return base.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
FormResponse response;
var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("test.json"))
using (var jsonReader = new CustomJsonReader(streamReader))
{
    response = serializer.Deserialize<FormResponse>(jsonReader);
}
```

In this case, the `FormDetail` property does not need the `JsonProperty` attribute.